# How to design solr searchhandler in core mode and how to use it?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 6.1.0 and not use cloud mode,

I has add searchhandler in solrconfig.xml and it's work, can see the search results

But when I use this searchhandler and add query in URL it'll error

Like this :

http://localhost:8983/solr/testcorea/contentsearch?indent=on&q=%22test%22&wt=json&shards=localhost:8983/solr/testcorea,localhost:8983/solr/testcoreb,localhost:8983/solr/testcorec,localhost:8983/solr/testcored

This is my searchhandler:

```
<requestHandler name="/contentsearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="wt">json</str>
        <str name="indent">true</str>

        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">
        title^100.0 content^80.0 text^5.0
        </str>
        <str name="q">*:*</str>
        <str name="indent">true</str>
        <str name="rows">10</str>

        <!-- Facet settings -->
        <str name="facet">on</str>
        <str name="facet.field">content_type</str>
        <str name="facet.field">category</str>
        <str name="facet.field">author</str>
        <str name="facet.field">editor</str>
        <str name="facet.field">source_type</str>

        <str name="hl">on</str>
        <str name="hl.fl">title content</str>
        <str name="hl.preserveMulti">true</str>
    </lst>    
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Error message :

=========================================================================

## {"responseHeader":{"status":404,"QTime":10,"params":{"q":"\"test\"","shards":"localhost:8983/solr/testcorea,localhost:8983/solr/testcoreb,localhost:8983/solr/testcorec,localhost:8983/solr/testcored","indent":"on","wt":"json"}},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException"],"msg":"Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/testcorec: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. \n\n\nError 404 Not Found\n\n

### HTTP ERROR 404

\n

Problem accessing /solr/testcorec/contentsearch. Reason:\n

```
    Not Found
```

\n\n\n","code":404}}

When I use solr default searchhandlr and query url it'll work
Like this :

http://localhost:8983/solr/testcorea/browse?indent=on&q=%22test%22&wt=json&shards=localhost:8983/solr/testcorea,localhost:8983/solr/testcoreb,localhost:8983/solr/testcorec,localhost:8983/solr/testcored

does anyone know what's different?

and why it does not work?

Thanks

Comment: Did you reload the core after changing the solrconfig.xml? Have you checked the config files via the admin UI to see if that search handler is there in the solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Hi @Jayce444 Yes, when I has change solrconfig.xml I'll restart solr service and I confirm the solrconfig.xml has been change.

Comment: And you checked the config of all 4 cores? (looks like the handler isn't in the config of testcorec)

Comment: @Jayce444 It's work now, thanks, 

But I still not understand the rank it has mapping the keyword but it does not to highlight Like this :

KeyWord: Test

"docid": {
"title": [
"<em>Test</em>"
],
"content": [
"0x0100AAFC59B5DB221440A574F622D4A674BFTest277813Not AffectedNot Affectedduplicate of 2424158/1"
]
},

In the content I found the keyword but I does not to highlight, why?

Comment: Have a look at vinod's answer. You have to enable highlighting, it's not on by default

Comment: I has enable highlighting in my searchhandler you can see up,
I don't know why the title filed have keyword and it has highlight ,content field it have keyword too ,but it was not highlight like this:
KeyWord: Test 
"title": [ "<em>Test</em>" ]
"content": [ "0x0100AAFC59B5DB221440A574F622D4A674BFTest277813Not AffectedNot Affectedduplicate of 2424158/1" ]   you can find the keyword in content field ,but it was not highlight

Answer (score 1):

Add highlighting parameters to URL.

Add hl=on and hl.fl=field_name to your url

ex:

`hl.fl=title&hl=on&indent=on&q=test`

Comment: Hi Vinod,

I has enable highlighting in my searchhandler you can see up,
I don't know why the title filed have keyword and it has highlight,
content field it have keyword too,
but it was not highlight 
like this: 
KeyWord: Test 
"title": [ "<em>Test</em>" ] 
"content": [ "0x0100AAFC59B5DB221440A574F622D4A674BFTest277813Not AffectedNot Affectedduplicate of 2424158/1" ] 

you can find the keyword in content field ,but it was not highlight

Comment: `content` field in schema file should be set `stored=true`. check on that.

Comment: the stored is true in content field

Comment: you have included content field in hl.fl param rite.? `hl.fl=title content` OR I think no proper encoding is done for content field value.

Comment: I try to just highlight title, but it does not have highlighting, and i confirm the title field have keyword. why it does not highlighting?